# Dynamic Time dimension in SSAS

Tags: ssas

As I am created a cube. Everything I setup fine except Time dimension. I need to follow Fiscal Year Calendar. Since, I am working on the product so there is no fixed Fiscal year format in which I cannot create `Time` dimension table using Server/datasource approach. at design time.

I have a table in which the format is there for fiscal year. something like below,

```
StartDM      EndDM        Year

 04-01       03-31        2014
```

So, I need to use the above format for fiscal year to use as a dimension. I searched a lot to find a way to achieve the functionality. Experts help me to provide a better solution to this problem. I ll be appreciating you.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure that I got the main idea. Do you need dynamic fiscal year? So one user can select FY started from April, another one -- started from October and so on? Or there will be only one kind of Fiscal Year, that you determined statically?

Comment: Since, It is the product we cannot always go to cube and change the fiscal year for different clients. One may wants to use fiscal year from April, another one -- started from October. So we need the flexibility to use the config/table value to determine the starting and ending fiscal year instead of selecting Start year and End Year statically in the cube development.

Comment: Got it, I wrote one of possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using many-to-many technique may help to solve it.

We need several additional items:

**SQL Part**

1) Flat dimension with members from January to December, this will be the first month of fiscal year.

```
create view vwDynamicFYStartMonth
as
SELECT 1 AS FYM_ID, 'Jan' AS FYMonth UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Feb' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Mar' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Apr' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'May' UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Jun' UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Jul' UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Aug' UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'Sep' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Oct' UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'Nov' UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'Dec'
```

2) Bridge measure group to have any combination of dates according to chosen start month.

3) Hierarchical dimension: Fiscal Year / Month / Day

We'll use the same view for both of them just to simplify solution:

```
create view vwBridge_M2M_DynamicFYStartMonth
as
select YMD,FYM_ID,FYMonth
    ,case when YMD/100%100>=FYM_ID and FYM_ID!=1 then YMD+10000 else YMD end as FYMD
    ,case when YMD/100%100>=FYM_ID and FYM_ID!=1 then (YMD+10000)/100 else YMD/100 end as FYM
    ,case when YMD/100%100>=FYM_ID and FYM_ID!=1 then (YMD+10000)/10000 else YMD/10000 end as FY
 from 
(select REPORT_DATE_ID as YMD from Data
 group by REPORT_DATE_ID) a
cross join vwDynamicFYStartMonth b
```

`Data.REPORT_DATE_ID` -- all possible values of our dates. Here should be the date dimension's day level field.

So we have smth like that:

[image: DynamicFY_BridgeSample]

Where `YMD` - is a real date, `FYM_ID` - is all possible months to start fiscal year, `FYMD, FYM, FY` - levels of FY Date dimension

**SSAS DSV Part**

Than we need to add all new items to Data Source View like this:

[image: DynamicFY_DSV]

`DimReportDateFYChoise` is view `vwDynamicFYStartMonth`

`BridgeReportDateFY` is `YMD, FYM_ID, FYMD` fields from view `vwBridge_M2M_DynamicFYStartMonth`

`DimReportDateFY` is `FYMD, FYM, FY` fields from view `vwBridge_M2M_DynamicFYStartMonth`

**SSAS Dimensions Part**

Create simple flat dimension on `DimReportDateFYChoise` with list of members (it's also desirable to remove ALL-level by setting `IsAggregatable = False` and set default member to `Jan` or any other)

Create hierarchical date dimension using `DimReportDateFY`.

**SSAS Cube Design Part**

Add intermediate measure group via BridgeReportDateFY (with one count measure)

Add two previously created dimensions to the cube and link dimensions as on the screen below:
[image: DynamicFY_DimUsage]

First link to your real dimension key of fact table (Report_Date_ID).

Second add new FY-dimensions to your real measure group by using Many-to-Many relation.

**MDX Querying**

I used this query for testing

```
select [Report Date FY].[Report Date FY].[Month].Allmembers on 1
,[Report Date].[Report Date].[Month].Allmembers on 0
from 
[DATA]
where ([Report Date FY Choise].[FYM ID].&[1],[Measures].[Count])
```

And than play with `&[1]` (which is January), `4` is April, `12` is December.

**Final Results**

For January it's obviously the same:

[image: DynamicFY_ResultJan]

April moves some members to the next year:

[image: DynamicFY_ResultApr]

Finally, for September to the next year moved only last 4 members of current year:

[image: DynamicFY_ResultOct.png]

Best of luck!

(updated due so small bugs fixes)

Comment: I have tried to create a view table that generate the columns with values required to build a dimension in cube. Pl see the post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558905/create-olap-datetime-table-dynamically-using-sql-views). If you have any ideas share with me,