# Create OLAP Datetime table dynamically using SQL Views

Tags: sql-server, olap

As I want to use the dynamic datetime values to pass as dimension in my OLAP Cube. Since, There is specific FY format for us. So, I decided to go with sql views. I have partly done writing my sql views. I need to have all the columns as when DateTime table created using Cube wizard. `ie, PK_Date, Date_Name, Fiscal_Year, Fiscal_Year_Name, Fiscal_Half_Year, Fiscal_Half_Year_Name etc....`

But, Only change with generating DateTime table from cube wizard is, in our approach we are going to use view table as source table for DateTime dimension.

**As far now I have done the below code**

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[FYExtraction] AS WITH E1(N) AS
(SELECT 1
 FROM (
     VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) DT(N)),
       E2(N) AS
(SELECT 1
 FROM E1 A, E1 B),
       E4(N) AS
(SELECT 1
 FROM E2 A, E2 B),
       Numbers(N) AS
( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                          ORDER BY
                            (SELECT NULL)) - 1
 FROM E4 )
SELECT temp.PK_Date,
   CASE
       WHEN (temp.PK_Date >= cast(cast(year(temp.PK_Date) AS varchar(10))+'-'+
                                    (SELECT Line2
                                     FROM SiteFile
                                     WHERE code='ACQFY') AS datetime)
             AND temp.PK_Date <= cast(cast(year(temp.PK_Date)+1 AS varchar(10))+'-'+
                                        (SELECT Line3
                                         FROM SiteFile
                                         WHERE code='ACQFY') AS datetime)) THEN 'FY '+ cast(year(temp.PK_Date) AS varchar(100))
       ELSE 'FY '+cast(year(temp.PK_Date) -1 AS varchar(100))
   END AS Fiscal_Year_Name
FROM
(SELECT N,
      DATEADD(D, N,
                (SELECT cast(
                               (SELECT top 1 cast(year(CreatedOn)-1 AS varchar(10))
                                FROM items
                                ORDER BY CreatedOn ASC)+'-'+Line2 AS datetime)
                 FROM sitefile
                 WHERE code='ACQFY')) AS PK_Date
 FROM Numbers
 WHERE N <= DATEDIFF(D,
                     (SELECT cast(
                                    (SELECT top 1 cast(year(CreatedOn)-1 AS varchar(10))
                                     FROM items
                                     ORDER BY CreatedOn ASC)+'-'+Line2 AS datetime)
                      FROM sitefile
                      WHERE code='ACQFY'),
                     (SELECT cast(
                                    (SELECT top 1 cast(year(CreatedOn)+1 AS varchar(10))
                                     FROM items
                                     ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC)+'-'+Line3 AS datetime)
                      FROM sitefile
                      WHERE code='ACQFY')))AS TEMP GO
```

Comment: An Analysis Services cube can use views as a source of dimension data, sure (although I don't recommend this for large dimensions, as you run into performance and data stability issues). What's your question?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I need to use dynamic FY format for my DateTime dimension. Is there any default or better way of doing it?? If not possible, I suppose to go with the above said sql views approach.

Comment: Dynamic based on what? A dimension is not dynamic -- its values need to be constant. You can have as many different formats per row as you like, as long as you calculate all of them. Your fact table would link to one particular row in your time dimension, and that row can then contain all the formats. To fill this table, you would usually use an import job to extract it from your fact data and store it, rather than a view that has to recalculate everything all the time.

Comment: I do not have Fixed FY for DateTime dimension or table in the db. Or even I cannot create DateTime table either by using `Generate a Time table in the datasource / Server option`. There will be a information regarding FY in the other table in the db. So, I need to use that FY settings to build a DateTime dimension. The data may be like, `Apr-01 to Mar-31` or `Jan-01 to Dec-31` or etc. You got it ??

Comment: No, sorry. I hope someone else does.